# Number of triplets of collinear points in a standard setting

Tags: combinatorics

This might be a stupd inquiry, but I was working on something and stumbled upon this question: if say we are given $n$ points in plane that determine $k$ distinct lines, what is the number of triplets of collinear points?

Any help would be really appreciated

Sorry if it turns out to be too trivial or too hard to find some bounds. (I'm just tired of thinking about it without luck)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there can be many values of triplets of collinear points (3 points lying in a line) ,

minimum value can be zero if no 3 points lie in a line, in this case k = (n)C(2)

finding maximum value,
if 3 points are not collinear then they form 3 lines,
if 3 points become collinear then  they constitute 1 line,

so every triplet of collinear points reduces the number of lines by 2,

number of triplets (maximum) = (nC2 - k)/2

Answer (score 0):

For the count of Collinear triplets, identify a line with any two points and then check whether a new line formed by any other two points might be coinciding or parallel and that needs to be taken care of while computing the collinear triplets.

To solve:
1. First, collect all points on a line using `Map<Line, Set<Point2d>>` as suggested in the question itself.
2. For triplets filter out those lines which have at least three points
3. Then compute nC3 for each of those add to global result.

> Code for the above problem below

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class CollinearTriplets {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Point2d A[] = new Point2d[8];
            A[0] = new Point2d(0, 0);
            A[1] = new Point2d(1, 1);
            A[2] = new Point2d(2, 2);
            A[3] = new Point2d(3, 3);
            A[4] = new Point2d(3, 2);
            A[5] = new Point2d(4, 2);
            A[6] = new Point2d(5, 1);
            A[7] = new Point2d(4, 4);

            System.out.println(countCollinear(A));
        }


        public static int factorial(int n) {
            int fact = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                fact = fact * i;
            }
            return fact;
        }

        private static int combinations(int n, int r) {
            return factorial(n) / (factorial(n - r) * factorial(r));
        }

        private static long countCollinear(Point2d[] points) {
            Map<Line, Set<Point2d>> lineToPoints = new HashMap<>();
            long result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
                    double slope = 0d, xIntercept, yIntercept; // Default slope paralell to y-axis
                    if (points[i].x == points[j].x) {
                        slope = Double.MAX_VALUE; // Horizontal slope parallel to x-axis
                    } else if (points[i].y != points[j].y) {
                        xIntercept = points[j].x - points[i].x;
                        yIntercept = points[j].y - points[i].y;
                        slope = yIntercept / xIntercept;
                    }
                    Line currLine = new Line(points[i], slope);
                    if (Objects.isNull(lineToPoints.get(currLine))) {
                        lineToPoints.put(currLine, new HashSet<>());
                    }
                    lineToPoints.get(currLine).add(points[i]);
                    lineToPoints.get(currLine).add(points[j]);
                }

            }
            for (Line line : lineToPoints.keySet()) {
                int size = lineToPoints.get(line).size();
                if (size >= 3) {
                    result = result + combinations(size, 3);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        /**
         * Line which contains the starting point and slope so that you can identify exact line
         * equals method is overridden to check whether any new line is coinciding or parallel
         */
        static class Line {
            Point2d point;
            double slope;

            public Line(Point2d point, double slope) {
                this.point = point;
                this.slope = slope;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (!(o instanceof Line)) return false;
                Line line = (Line) o;

                if (line.slope == this.slope)
                    return ((((double) (line.point.y - this.point.y)) / (line.point.x - this.point.x)) == this.slope);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(slope);
            }
        }

        static class Point2d {
            int x;
            int y;

            public Point2d(int x, int y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object o) {
                if (this == o) return true;
                if (!(o instanceof Point2d)) return false;
                Point2d point2d = (Point2d) o;
                return x == point2d.x &&
                        y == point2d.y;
            }

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

The time complexity for above code `O(N^2)` and space complexity is `O(N)`